# Single row responsive menu with margin: 0 auto and position absolute

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I'm currently working on a responsive layout that consists of two fixed width elements positioned via `position: absolute` and middle element that is centred via `margin: 0 auto`. The wrapper element has a `padding: left` and `padding: right` to push the middle element away from two fixed elements.

With the correct HTML structure `left, middle, right`, the `right` element is pushed into the next row because the `middle` element is a normal block element.

Is there another way fix this in CSS without having to change the HTML structure `left, right, middle` and still use `margin: 0 auto` to center the middle element?

See JS bin for a live demo: http://jsbin.com/kucohewoyole/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is just add `top:0px` to the class   **.right**

<kbd>[Js Bin](http://jsbin.com/kucohewoyole/3/)</kbd>